# Activating child theme returns "active theme is broken"

Tags: child-theme

I was using the [Pinboard](https://wordpress.org/extend/themes/pinboard) theme, but want to make modifications to it.  Instead of editing the theme files directly, I wanted to try to make my changes using a child theme.

Following the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), I created a new folder named **pinboard-child** under **/wp-content/themes/**.  I created a **style.css** file, added the code below, and threw it in the folder.

```
/*
Theme Name: Pinboard Child
Theme URI: 
Template: pinboard-child
Description: Child theme for the Pinboard theme
Author: One Designs, modified by me
Version: 1.0
Tags: 
*/

@import url("../pinboard/style.css");

body {
   background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

(I added the body styling just to see if everything worked as expected)

I navigated to **/wp-content/themes/pinboard-child/style.css** to verify my file was in the correct location, and everything showed correctly.

After I network-enabled the theme, I found the theme sitting in my Appearance menu, although the preview image was gray.  I clicked on "activate", and Wordpress came back with the message "The active theme is broken. Reverting to the default theme." and set my site's theme to Twenty Twelve.

After scouring the internet, I'm at a complete loss as to what more I can do.  Does anyone know 1. what might be causing this issue and/or 2. what I might be able to do to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Template" should reference the parent theme:

```
Template: Pinboard
```

Comment: You've got to be _absolutely kidding me_.  I _destroyed_ that codex page, taking each step slowly so I wouldn't screw anything up, and I do _that_?!
I can't believe it.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: time to catch some sleep ;)